# Script not displaying output

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to write a simple script. I want to ask for inputs and then calculate a power.t.test.

```
numberoftests <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Number of samples? "))
rangedata <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Range? "))
Sdev <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Standard deviation? "))
P<- power.t.test(n=numberoftests,delta=rangedata,sd= Sdev,power=NULL)
```

And then this is the output I get

```
> source('~/R/power.R')
Number of samples? 2
Range? 0.10
Standard deviation? 0.07
> 
> 
>
```

If I set the formula as a variable I can see it in the environment window, so I know it's calculating.
How do I get the results to display?

Comment: Try print(P)...

Comment: print(P) worked! I downloaded packages 'knitr' and then 'printr', I don't know if I needed to do that but I did so just in case

Comment: You don't need that...